# How to append streaming data to a specific location in a file using node and retrieving?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a bot that helps moderators on a website and I would like to add artificial intelligence. This is based off Markov Chains. The problem is that I would like all of the data strings to be logged by the bot and then used in the Markov Chain. essentially the bot is learning from the chat data it collects from the users talking.

what I have at the moment is:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var logit = fs.createWriteStream('Data.js', {'flags': 'a'});

chatEvent(function(data) {
    data.message = stringFix(data.message); //just fixes punctuation
    a = JSON.stringify(data.message);
    logit.write(a + ',');
});
```

this creates a list of messages (snippet) like so:

```
"Shall I play Ellie Goulding - Hanging On (Sound Remedy Remix)",
"Or Mango - Sayonara",
"mmn mangos",
"What should I choose",
"only because you're thinking food",
"how can you expect a woman to be happy if a man persists in treating her like a perfectly normal human being",
```

what I would like for it to do is to do this:

```
module.exports = {
    data: [
        "Shall I play Ellie Goulding - Hanging On (Sound Remedy Remix)",
        "Or Mango - Sayonara",
        "mmn mangos",
        "What should I choose",
        "only because you're thinking food",
        "how can you expect a woman to be happy if a man persists in treating her like a perfectly normal human being",
    ]
}
```

so that all of the messages save within the data: [] array. that way I can call a static view of the data when the time comes to the bot using the AI by doing:

```
Data = require('./Data').data;
sentences = [];
sentences = Data;
```

is there a way to do this? also is it possible to live stream from the Data.js file so that it adds all of the new messages into the sentences array as it is being sent to the file, that way my bot is constantly learning. if not I can set it up so that all of the messages are saved to the data.js file and pushed to the sentences file, that way, if the bot crashes/reconnects, it can reload the data from the data.js file and pick up from where it left off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can "init" the js file and then insert your data
A implementation could be the like this.

```
var fs = require("fs");
var fcontent = 'module.exports = {data: []}';

fs.writeFile('Data.js', fcontent, function (err) {
    var offset= 25;
    var logit = fs.createWriteStream('Data.js', {flags: 'r+',start:offset});

    function beforeRead(cbk){
        logit.write("]};");
        cbk();
    }

    function message(msg){
        logit.write( (offset==25) ? ('"'+msg+'"') : (',"'+msg+'"') );
        offset+=msg.length;
    } 
    //chatEvent
    message("I'm a bot");
    message("I can't hurt you");
    beforeRead(function(){
        //here we have a correct syntax js file
    });
});
```

Even you can inject the initial write in the if but it will lose readability. Act with care, this could be dangerous (scape strings, catch errors, ...)